# How to set specific fields input class manually in 'Laravel's Voyager'?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am setting up an inventory app using the Voyager library, and want to add input classes for specific fields from `$row->field`. How to set it up in the edit-add blade file?

Comment: I could able to fix through javascript. Any other solutions please update. Thanks.

Comment: if you have specific needs you can ovverride any view as here `add-edit.blade.php` of particular modules. take a look at [voyager doc ovverriding files](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/overriding-files)

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it's not possible to add classes to BREAD fields yet. but actually there is an alternative way to achieve what you willing:

you can add an **ID** to field's container using BREAD [display option](https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/core-concepts/bread-builder#display-options)

just goto bread > MODEL > edit > ATTRIBUTE and change its option details to

```
{
    "display": {
        "width": "3",
        "id": "custom_id"
    }
}
```

click Submit and it's done.

Comment: How to apply this on relationship?

Comment: This works for the parent div. Not for the input itself ...